# how to redirect the page url when it fails?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I want to redirect the page when it fails,
Accessing the page with this works fine

```
http://192.168.0.114:8686/test/1/
http://192.168.0.114:8686/test/2/
```

but when I try to access this http://192.168.0.114:8686/test it throughs an error, when the error occurs it want the value as `"page_no=1"`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^test/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$', views.test.as_view(), name='test_page'),
]
```

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.0.114:8686/test
Using the URLconf defined in couponer.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^ ^$ [name='api-root']
^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
admin/
^ ^^p//$ [name='udemylinks-list']
^ ^^p\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='udemylinks-list']
^ ^^p//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='udemylinks-detail']
^ ^^p//(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='udemylinks-detail']
^ ^$ [name='api-root']
^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
^pages/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$ [name='Pages']
^html/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$ [name='index']
^test/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$ [name='test_page']
The current path, test, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 0):

So when it throws a 404 error you want it to redirect?

**Option 1: Client Side Redirect**

1. Create a page called 404.html and place it in your templates folder.
2. Put this code on the 404 page.

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "{% url 'studies:index' %}"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
}, 2000);
</script>
```

**Option 2: Server Side Redirect**

In your project's main `urls.py`, you can do something like this:

```
if not settings.DEBUG:
    handler400 = 'myapp.views.bad_request'
    handler403 = 'myapp.views.permission_denied'
    handler404 = 'myapp.views.page_not_found'
```

and have `views.py` in the app which you want to handle errors changed to this:

```
def bad_request(request):
    return redirect('index')

def permission_denied(request):
    return redirect('index')

def page_not_found(request):
    return redirect('index')
```